# Spring web project with Maven at eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have recently practice on spring with maven. But face flowing problem.
After updating project at maven-> update project it shown cross sign at java Resources.
and when i run this project it shown flowing error:

```
Feb 27, 2015 5:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 27, 2015 5:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

please assist me if anyone knows the exact solution.
[image]

Comment: could you post your spring-xml?

Comment: Could you also post web.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Add this to your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `spring-web` dependency. This is where the class `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` is declared.

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version> <!-- replace with your Spring version -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If  everything  is fine related to configuration  and still you are getting  `ClassNotFoundException` then check your maven deployment configuration at least once.

> Right click on project-->>Select deployment Assembly >> then press on add button and then >> select java build path entries (Maven  libraries should be there if everything is fine) add then >> Apply and done.:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just find out this problem solution.
After change tomcat server 7 to 6 and add runt it's given write output.